# Deploying Silverlight website using webdeploy succeeds but website and files are not updating/changed

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

When publishing a silverlight website using visualstudio 2013, webdeployment method VS reports that publishing succeeded. 
But when viewing the site my changes are not visible. When checking the files on the server in wwwinetpub i can see that the files(like the xap) are not updated.

Has anyone got any idea if i'm missing something obvious or what i should do to fix this?

I have also tried importing webdeploy package (.zip) and this also tells me it succeeded but still the files are not updated....

I'm at a loss.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out... (feeling bit stupid now) ... There was a mismatch between the buildconfiguration setting of the editor (vs2013) and the publish settings. 
This is what happend.

I "Want" to publish te debug build to a debug url. So in my publish settings I specify the debug build configuration. Only the editor was still in release mode. So I think executing publish does not build the chosen configuration but rather copy's the last build of the chosen configuration, or execute a build command without communicating the setting in the publish settings -> builds the release instead of the debug -> copy's OLD debug build in package.

Anyway. Fixed now... hope this shamefull experience can be of help to someone somewhere in the future ... :P